# Get and sum all association's data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 models. Company and Orders. Company has many orders. Orders table has a quantity column. 
I need to fetch orders and sum all quantities belong to each company.

Below code is not working.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  belongs_to :payment_method
end
```

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  validates :company_id, presence: true
  validates :quantity, presence: true
  belongs_to :company
end
```

```
<%  @companies.each do |p| %>
  <p><%=  p.orders.quantity.sum %></p>
<%  end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p.orders` accesses the associated table. The reason this code isn't working: after getting the associated records, you must iterate over each to add up their quantities.

Here's one way to do that.

```rb
p.orders.sum(&:quantity)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help ,  i need to make a control like: if company's total quantity is bigger 500, i will multiply quantity with a value. How i can do it in this iteration.

Comment: @CrazyCoders glad to help. That sounds like a different question, perhaps you should ask it separately?